# resolution of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm following a course on algebraic geometry and have to make an assignment about the resolution of singularities. In this assignment I have to explain canonical divisors and log resolutions. I'm probably missing the entire point, but I don't see what these two concepts have to do with the resolution of singularities. I thought that resolving a singularity is all about taking a blow up, so can someone explain me what I'm missing?

Comment: Log resolutions are something like resolutions in the category of pairs, which tends to be more robust for birational purposes. One often relates a variety to its resolution by comparing canonical divisors, and this is even more explicitly necessary in the log category.